# ASP.NET MVC ViewSource code full indent

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Is there an automatic way to output full indent code using a MVC solution?

When my HTML is output the code inside partialviews and childviews is not indented because it's not declared so (imagine how many tabs i have to indent to become indent, and that is illegible inside VStudio).

Comment: Normally you should compact and compress your output HTML as much as possible to decrease its size, limit bandwidth consumption and make your pages load faster. As a reference take a look at the HTML code of http://www.google.com to see what I mean. So instead of indenting you should be doing exactly the opposite => removing whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't format your code so that View | Source is indented.

Rather, if you need to explore the structure of your HTML syntax as output to the browser, use something like FireBug or the Chrome developer tools that automatically indent and structure the browser's HTML in a usable way.

Like so:

[image: (this is Firebug)]